# Why assignment to std::function<X()> doesn't compile when it is a member of class X?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

The following code doesn't compile:

```
#include <functional>

struct X
{
    std::function<X()> _gen;
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    x._gen = [] { return X(); }; //this line is causing problem!
}
```

I don't understand why assignment to `x._gen` is causing problem. Both [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85bdaa8349d2c7eb) and [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d278fb63cc2dadb9) are giving similar error messages. Could anyone please explain it?

---

#### Compiler error messages

[GCC's error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85bdaa8349d2c7eb):

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional: In instantiation of ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Requires<std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_CheckResult<std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Invoke<_Functor>, _Res>, std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&> std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator=(_Functor&&) [with _Functor = main()::__lambda0; _Res = X; _ArgTypes = {}; std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Requires<std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_CheckResult<std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Invoke<_Functor>, _Res>, std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&> = std::function<X()>&]’:
main.cpp:11:12:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2333:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::function<X()>::function(main()::__lambda0)’
    function(std::forward<_Functor>(__f)).swap(*this);
    ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2333:4: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2255:2: note: template<class _Functor, class> std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor)
  function(_Functor);
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2255:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2230:7: note: std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&&) [with _Res = X; _ArgTypes = {}]
       function(function&& __x) : _Function_base()
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2230:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘main()::__lambda0’ to ‘std::function<X()>&&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2433:5: note: std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(const std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&) [with _Res = X; _ArgTypes = {}]
     function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2433:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘main()::__lambda0’ to ‘const std::function<X()>&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2210:7: note: std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(std::nullptr_t) [with _Res = X; _ArgTypes = {}; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]
       function(nullptr_t) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2210:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘main()::__lambda0’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2203:7: note: std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function() [with _Res = X; _ArgTypes = {}]
       function() noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2203:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Likewise, [Clang throws](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d278fb63cc2dadb9) this:

```
main.cpp:11:12: error: no viable overloaded '='
    x._gen = [] { return X(); };
    ~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/functional:2270:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '<lambda at main.cpp:11:14>' to 'const std::function<X ()>' for 1st argument
      operator=(const function& __x)
      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/functional:2288:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '<lambda at main.cpp:11:14>' to 'std::function<X ()>' for 1st argument
      operator=(function&& __x)
      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/functional:2302:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '<lambda at main.cpp:11:14>' to 'nullptr_t' for 1st argument
      operator=(nullptr_t)
      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/functional:2192:39: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _Functor = <lambda at main.cpp:11:14>]
        using _Requires = typename enable_if<_Cond::value, _Tp>::type;
                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/functional:2340:2: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'reference_wrapper<type-parameter-0-0>' against '<lambda at main.cpp:11:14>'
        operator=(reference_wrapper<_Functor> __f) noexcept
        ^
```

Comment: For what it's worth, Visual Studio 2012 accepts this code.

Comment: @dauphic: If it is a compiler bug, then it is interesting to see that Visual C++ got it right this time.

Comment: Mine clang accepts it. I guess the question is: can `std::function` be declared with incomplete type.

Comment: @zch No, it is not explicitly allowed. But I'm not sure if `X()` is an incomplete type.

Comment: @zch: I don't find any reason why it cannot be declared with incomplete type: it doesn't store *data* of the class type. Also, `X()` is not an incomplete type as far as I can reason.

Comment: @Nawaz, doesn't matter. IIRC Implementation of standard template might assume that type arguments are complete types, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: It turns out `X()` is not incomplete type and can be declared within definition of `class X`. I'm still not 100% positive whole code legal - I'm not sure what is "template argument when instantiating a template component" here, given the partial specialization of `std::function`.

Comment: FWIW, Clang 3.3 is accepting this fine on my Mac (Clang version: Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)). I'm speculating here, but I wouldn't be surprised if this was a bug in GCC/libstdc++.

Comment: GCC 4.9.2 compiles it whithout a problem

Comment: To add to @SeverinPappadeux's comment: so do 4.8.4, 4.7.4, 4.6.4, and 4.5.4. 4.4.7 rejects it, but that's only because lambdas were only introduced in 4.5. In fact, it works even on Coliru now: follow the links in this question to the errors, click "Edit", and without changing anything, click "Compile, link and run...": no more errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was [PR60594](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR60594), which got fixed in GCC 4.8.3. The comments on that bug point out why it is valid: although the standard requires template arguments for standard library templates to be a complete type (with some exceptions), `X()` is a complete type even if `X` is not.

There are several members of `std::function<X()>` that do implicitly require `X` to be a complete type. The template constructor you're using is one of them: it requires the return type of your lambda to be implicitly convertible to `X`, but whether `X` is convertible to itself depends on whether `X` is a complete type: if it's incomplete, the compiler can't rule out the possibility that it is an uncopyable unmovable type.

This requirement follows from:

> **20.9.11.2.1 function construct/copy/destroy [func.wrap.func.con]**
>
> 8 *Remarks:* These constructors shall not participate in overload resolution unless `f` is Callable (20.9.11.2) for argument types `ArgTypes...` and return type `R`.
>
> **20.9.11.2 Class template function [func.wrap.func]**
>
> 2 A callable object `f` of type `F` is *Callable* for argument types `ArgTypes` and return type `R` if the expression *`INVOKE`*`(f, declval<ArgTypes>()..., R)`, considered as an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), is well formed (20.9.2).
>
> **20.9.2 Requirements [func.require]**
>
> 2 Define *`INVOKE`*`(f, t1, t2, ..., tN, R)` as *`INVOKE`*`(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` implicitly converted to `R`.

Several other members of `std::function` also require `X` to be a complete type.

You're only using that constructor *after* type `X` has already completed, though, so there's no problem: at that point, `X` certainly can be implicitly converted to `X`.

The problem was that `std::function` was performing checks that depend on `X` being a complete type, in a context where the standard doesn't support performing such checks, and this did not account for the possibility that `X` would become a complete type after the instantiation of `std::function<X()>` had already completed.

Answer (score 7):

This may be a gcc bug, but maybe not.  It isn't *directly* in `=` but rather in the conversion constructor for `std::function` (which the `operator=` invokes).

Here is a pathological example of it happening:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct X
{
  std::function<X()> _gen;
};

X func() {return {};};

int main()
{
  std::function<X()> foo1( &func ); // compiles
  X unused = X{}; // copy ctor invoked
  std::function<X()> foo2( &func ); // does not compile!
}
```

note that the first `foo1` works fine, it is not until I cause some code somewhere to invoke the copy ctor that the second one generates errors.  Even `auto unused =[]{ return X{}; };` is enough.  (`func` direct constructs and never copies).

It is the use/"creation" of the copy ctor that seems to cause the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct X
{
  std::function<X()> _gen;
  X( X const& ) = default;
  X() = default;
};
X func() {return {};};

int main()
{
  std::function<X()> foo1( &func ); // does not compile
}
```

that copy constructor ends up calling the copy ctor of `_gen`, possibly before `X` is a complete type.

If we explicitly delay instantiation of `X::X(X const&)` until `X` is a complete type:

```
#include <functional>

struct X
{
  std::function<X()> _gen;
  X( X const& );
  X() {}
};
X::X( X const& o ):_gen(o._gen){} // or =default *here*

X func() {return {};};

int main()
{
  std::function<X()> foo1( &func ); // compiles!
  []{ return X{}; }; // or X unused = X{};
  std::function<X()> foo2( &func ); // compiles!
}
```

the problem goes away.

I suspect that the implicit copy constructor of `X` created in the body of `X` when `X` is an incomplete type implicitly invokes `std::function<X()>`'s copy constructor, which is in a context where `X` is incomplete, which breaks the preconditions of its copy constructor being invoked (at least in practice in how it was implemented in gcc -- by the standard?  I am unsure.)

By explicitly making a copy ctor outside of `X` I avoid this, and everything works.

So as a work around to your problem, declare and implement `X::X(X const&)` outside of `X`, and the magic error goes away.

Comment: g++4.8.1 also doesn't compile it when excluding the lambda, i.e. the second `foo2` declaration fails to compile, while the first does w/o complaint.

Comment: @DyP Same with g++4.8.2

Comment: Just because something is failing in a strange way (or only failing some of the time), doesn't mean it's a compiler bug. It could also be undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't understand how and where *copy-ctor* comes into picture in your code? How did you come to that conclusion? It is not evident from  *your* code.

Comment: @Nawaz It comes in where I called a conversion constructor a copy constructor!  Oops.

Comment: @interjay agreed -- hence "appears to be".  The fact that it behaves this strangely is some evidence that something funny is going on.

Comment: @DyP the assignment operator `SFINAE` template succeeds (see the OPs error message), it is the body of the assignment operator that fails at the conversion constructor ( `std::function<X()>(rhs).swap(*this)` fails in the conversion constructor step )