# g++ 4.8.2: could not convert from function pointer to std::function<>

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to write a class that takes, as a constructor parameter, a factory function that creates another instance of the same class on a transformed version of the input.  For a trivial example, a functor class that takes an int, prints it, and returns another functor that prints the input's successor.

I'm getting errors of the form

```
error: could not convert 'foo' from 'Type(*)(int)' to 'std::function<Type(int)>'
```

The only seems to arise with factory functions passed into constructors.

Using a function pointer instead of a `std::function<>` works fine, but I was hoping that with C++11 I'd be able to avoid function pointers.

Here's an example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// std::function-returning-int param in ctor with default value
// This works fine

class PrInc; // "print and increment"

using Worker = std::function<int(int)>;

int foo(int i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return i+1;
}

class PrInc {
  public:
    PrInc(int i, Worker fn = foo) : i_(i), fn_(fn) {}
    int operator()() { return fn_(i_); }
  private:
    int i_;
    Worker fn_;
};

// std::function-returning-PrInc2 param in ctor with default value
// This fails, at least on g++ 4.8.2 --std=c++11

class PrInc2;

using Factory = std::function<PrInc2(int)>;
// Use function ptrs (instead of std::function<>s) and it works fine
//typedef PrInc2 (*Factory)(int);

PrInc2 bar(int);

class PrInc2 {
  public:
    PrInc2(int i, Factory fn = bar) : i_(i), fn_(fn) {}
    PrInc2 operator()() { return fn_(i_); }
  private:
    int i_;
    Factory fn_;
};

PrInc2 bar(int i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return PrInc2(i+1);
    // error: could not convert 'bar' from 'PrInc2 (*)(int) to 'Factory {aka std::function<PrInc2(int)>'
}

int main() {
    auto p1 = PrInc {1};
    auto p2 = PrInc{p1()};
    p2();

    auto p3 = PrInc2 {1};
    // error: could not convert 'bar' from 'PrInc2 (*)(int) to 'Factory {aka std::function<PrInc2(int)>'
    auto p4 = p3();
    p4();

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** thelink2012's suggestion to try `PrInc2(int i, Factory fn = Factory(bar))` works fine on the "repro" above, but fails on the [motivating example](https://github.com/MattJOlson/DevProjects/tree/master/sandbox/dailyprogrammer/erdosnumbers) (GitHub link; relevant code is erdos.h:35-54 around ParseStep and ParseFunction).  Back to the drawing board for a better repro....

Comment: I think it's this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129601/why-assignment-to-stdfunctionx-doesnt-compile-when-it-is-a-member-of-clas

Comment: Meanwhile, try `PrInc2(int i, Factory fn = Factory(bar))` instead, [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3244fed38e7529d) on g++4.8.1 for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following part of your code, which is the only part that appears to be relevant to the compiler error you're asking about, compiles cleanly with gcc 4.9.2 using the `-std=c++11` mode:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using Worker = std::function<int(int)>;

int foo(int i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return i+1;
}

class PrInc {
  public:
    PrInc(int i, Worker fn = foo) : i_(i), fn_(fn) {}
    int operator()() { return fn_(i_); }
  private:
    int i_;
    Worker fn_;
};
```

Most likely a bug in the older gcc you're using. Upgrade to a more recent version of gcc.

Comment: That's the part of the code I'm not interested in, actually; it's there for contrast.  It's the stuff around std::function<PrInc2(int)> that errors.  I'll edit the original for clarity; I see where I screwed up the example.